# Hoow to cancel currently running request with redux-saga with parameter?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I want to cancel a request in redux saga upon clicking a button

The first saga here is the one fetching data from server

```js
function* fetchData({ payload: a, b, c}) {
  try {
    // ...API call

    action.success(data);
  } catch (e) {
    action.fail(e);
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) yield put(getDataCancelled());
  }
}
```

Then I have a button that when clicked, it will trigger the function below. The saga below is suppose to cancel the currently running request from the fetch above.

```js
function* stopFetchData({ payload }) {
  try {
    const task = yield fork(fetchData);
    // API Call to clean up data from server
    action.cancelSuccess(data);
    yield cancel(task);
  } catch (e) {
    action.cancelFailed(e);
  }
}

export function* fetchDataWatcher() {
   yield takeLatest(SET_DATA, fetchData);
}
```

But I'm having an error with the parameter and as soon as this is triggered the sagas stopped working since it is finding the parameters for the function.  I already tried adding the parameter, and what happens is, after clicking the fetch, and cancel. The cancel triggers, but the fetch still continues.

Comment: Did you read the docs?:) https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html To cancel a Saga is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Yup I did, but the sample on the docs didn't have parameters on the "fetchData" saga. I'm having an error that it is looking for the "payload" parameter. When I tried some way to pass the parameter. All it does is just rerun the fetchData saga and still continue, and it did not cancel the request.

Comment: plase share a codesandbox duplicating the error.

Comment: It just says an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined
    at fetchData. When trying to fork the fetchData

Comment: we'll so then your plain action object does not contain a payload property

Comment: @Ninay11 Were you able to solve this? I am facing similar issue